# youtube not operator isn't working via gnip

Tags: youtube, boolean, operator-keyword, gnip

I'm trying to get the YouTube NOT operator to work via Gnip, but am not having any luck.

I've tried searching for:
("dallas")-("dallas")

... which should be returning zero results, but isntead I get results for "dallas". When I search for ("black") | ("white") -("multiplayer"), I should get a lot of results for Call of Duty Black Opps that don't mention multiplayer, but this is also not the case. Both queries just seem to ignore the NOT operator.

If someone has this working, can they please provide an example snippet.

Thanks

Comment: What is this "|" operator? Don't you mean: (black OR white) -multiplayer

Answer (score -1):

Try getting rid of the parentheses and " characters like:

black | white -multiplayer

After a quick test, it looks like this will give you the right matching.